# Asp core 3.1 drawing image with right-to-left text like arabic problematic

Tags: fonts, pdf, arabic

Working with asp core 3.1, I am using PdfSharp to generate PDF document, this last, don't support Dotnet core on Linux(it is strongly coupled to windows, regarding the font), for that reason, i rebuild the library using CORE and CORE_WITH_GDI, in the begin looks like work great, but when try writing text to PDF, an big exception raised, any way, i tray to draw image with text, and insert it to pdf document with success, but, when draw an arabic text, the result is wrong in the direction
[sample of rendred text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAbB3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Complex Text Layout handling.

Something like Pango-HarfBuzz-FreBidi for GTK. I lack knowledge about MS technologies like DotNet and ASP. So I don't know how they call it.